# If we disable the AKS log analytics will it affect the AKS deployments or services?

Tags: azure, aks, log-analytics-workspace

If we disable the AKS monitoring add-on completely for AKS monitoring as mentioned below documents will it affect the AKS deployments or services?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-optout#azure-cli

where the Kubernetes logs are saved for AKS if we disable the monitoring add-on?